# Хочу проиницилизировать анимации в фрагменте

Tags: java, android

У меня выходит ошибка

````
private void initViews() {
        top = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(**R.anim.top_animation**);
        bottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(**R.anim.bottom_animation**);

        image = image.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        logoText = logoText.findViewById(R.id.textViewLogo);
        slogan = slogan.findViewById(R.id.textViewText);```
    }
````

Где выделено там ошибка, анимации есть
В MainActivity делал там иницилизация анимаций была удачной
Я решил перейти на фрагменты(**т.к много весил**), но тут я поймал ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at com.example.chcagorent.MainActivity.makeAnimation(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                                                        at com.example.chcagorent.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
```

Comment: В текущем виде на вопрос крайне сложно дать ответ. Вы говорите что у вас ошибка - но не говорите какая. Добавьте деталей в вопрос - что за ошибка когда и как возникает etc.

Comment: Смотрите я хочу сделать приложение сначала я его сделал с (**20 активити**) я хочу добавить анимацию на элементы.В активити ошибок не обнаружил, посмотрев на объем приложения ,я решил перейти на фрагменты, но тут я попал в капкан.Щас вы увидите код:

Comment: private void initViews() {
        top = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(**R.anim.top_animation**);
    }  Где выделено там и ошибка. Контекст я ставил ошибка.Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Кажется, у вас проблема не с анимациями, а с переносом кода из активити во фрагмент. Кода не вижу, так что могу лишь преполагать, что вам надо код из активити связанный с вьюхами и анимациями перенести в метод onViewCreated.

Comment: У меня выходит ошибка.Из-за того что я не знаю как проиницилизировать переменные анимаций